# I want to do a sql update loop statement, by using the do--while in php

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I want to loop the update statement, but it only loops once.

Here is the code I am using:

```
do {
    mysql_select_db($database_ll, $ll);
    $query_query= "update table set ex='$71[1]' where field='val'";
    $query = mysql_query($query_query, $ll) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_domain_all = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
} while ($row_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($query));
```

Thanks
Jean

Comment: Maybe you could explain what you're trying to do...?

Comment: What does that code do? What do you want it to do? What is your question?

Comment: refer the q again, sorry, had to type in quickly

Answer (score 5):

Well, the reason it's only looping once would be that `UPDATE` queries do not return any rows that you could extract with `mysql_fetch_assoc`. So `mysql_fetch_assoc` returns `false`, which renders the expression `($row_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))` `false`, which is why the  loop aborts.

Apart from that though, that code is, sorry to say, pretty atrocious. It might help telling us what it is you want to do, there must be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you reattribute a value to $query within your loop. Try

```
do {
    mysql_select_db($database_ll, $ll);
    $query_query= "update table set ex='$71[1]' where field='val'";
    $query2 = mysql_query($query_query, $ll) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_domain_all = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2);
} while ($row_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($query));
```

Comment: plus he is using mysql_fetch_assoc on an UPDATE query, which does not return any rows.

Comment: Actually no, he's only assigning to `$query` once within the loop, that shouldn't pose any problem.

Answer (score 0):

may be it has some problem in your mysql query.

$query_query= "update table set ex='$71[1]' where field='val'";

Your query is wrong.

update query is "update "table name" set ex='$71[1]' where field='val'";

You missed the table name.

or if you are using 'table' as your table name. then change it.

Answer (score 0):

People,

I needed to replace this

```
$query = mysql_query($query_query, $ll) or die(mysql_error());
$row_domain_all = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
```

With

```
$Result1 = mysql_query($query_query, $ll) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Sorry, but that makes no sense. If that's the solution you must have omitted half the problem from the question.